# Monitor celery tasks launched from task

Tags: django, asynchronous, parallel-processing, celery, celery-task

I have a celery task(super task) which further launches different celery tasks (sub tasks)

```
@app.task
def super_task():
    do_heavy_work()

@app.task
def sub_tasks():
    do_something()

def do_heavy_work():  
    results = group(sub_tasks.s() for i in xrange(100))()

    # Problem
    # Once code reach below line any tasks in pending state will 
    # remain in pending state until below code executes

    for _ in xrange(some_value):
        if not all(r.ready() for r in results):
            time.sleep(30)
        else:
            break

super_task.delay()
```

Question

How can track the status of all the sub tasks either with some signals or any other functionality without keeping them in pending state

Comment: Facing exactly the same problem today, since I want to get statistics about the `sub_tasks` success. If you have found a solution, I would be happy to hear about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach we use to resolve this is -Ofair argument in celery command as stated here.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html

Celery uses multiprocessing to spawn multiple processes per worker to execute tasks in parallel.
Now each worker process can prefetch tasks to optimize computing(default is 4).

So what happens is when you start polling to see if tasks are ready any tasks prefetch by this worker process will remain in pending state.

By using Ofair argument you tell celery to only fetch tasks when current task is finished and thus polling task will never prefetch a task.